# How to remove double-quotes in embedded arguments in robot framework while passing it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

how we will remove `""` in embedded arguments in robot fame work while passing it?

```
*** Keywords ***

"${abc}" place an outgoing call to "{xyz}" by using "{xyz_name}"
    ${result}  Set variable  "${abc}"
    Log  ${result}
    ${xyz}  Set variable  "${xyz}"
    Run keyword if  ${result}=="${abc}"  xyz Initiated Sign in
    ...  ELSE  abc Initated Sign in
    Log  "${abc}" initiated call request to "${xyz}"
    Click Element  com.gmail:id/action_bar_search_action
    Sleep  10s
    Input Text  com.gmail:id/search_src_text  "${xyz_name}"
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  1m  5s  Click Element  com.gmail:id/search_result_item_container
    Sleep  10s
    Log  "${abc}" placing call to "${xyz}"
```

Comment: by "inverted commas" do you mean "quotes"?

Comment: @BryanOakley  yes

Answer (score 4):

Robot will not add the quote marks unless you ask it to. At the very start of your keyword, `${abc}` and `${xyz}` will not have the quote characters.

You are explicitly adding quote marks here:

```
${result}  Set variable  "${abc}"
${xyz}  Set variable  "${xyz}"
```

If you don't want the quote marks, don't add the quote marks:

```
${result}  Set variable  ${abc}
${xyz}  Set variable  ${xyz}
```